# Optimise MySQL SQL Query that hangs DB Server

Tags: php, mysql, performance, inner-join

I am building a simple report for my own company needs which will display data, with inner joining two tables, below the sql query.

```
SELECT r.user
    ,CASE 
        WHEN LENGTH(r.extension) > 6
            THEN r.extension
        WHEN LENGTH(r.extension) < 6
            THEN number_dialed
        END AS Telefono
    ,r.server_ip
    ,r.start_time
    ,r.length_in_sec
    ,c.channel_group
    ,r.location
FROM recording_log r
INNER JOIN call_log c ON r.vicidial_id = c.uniqueid
WHERE r.extension NOT IN (
        '772'
        ,'55555'
        ,'5555'
        )
    AND r.location <> ''
    AND c.number_dialed NOT IN (
        '8368'
        ,'8369'
        )
    AND c.length_in_sec > 10
ORDER BY c.`recording_id`
```

The two tables needed are `recording_log (4,079,371 entries)` and `call_log (38,516,966 entries)`.

I have searched and made all the optimizations I could find to the MySql, now the problem stands on the query itself, especially when I try to use a Variable on the `WHERE` **(ex. WHERE number_dialed like '%334' )**

Comment: Is this `mysql` or `sql server`? Why are both tagged?

Comment: Mysql sorry, wrong tag removing it now

Comment: As a benchmark how fast does the query run with absolutely no where clauses?

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 1,178,843 total, Query took 0.0021 sec)

But the results come back after 3/4 minutes, plus from the htop the processor usage (1 core) goes to 100%

Comment: What do you want if `LENGTH(a.extension) = 6`?

Comment: "Showing rows..." -- Don't let your UI add `SQL_COUNT_ROWS_FOUND`; that's what is taking 45 seconds and 100% of a core.

Comment: Please use `r` and `c` for the table aliases; makes it easier to remember that `r` is `recording_log`; `a` gives no clue.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- I want to see which table it chose first.  Also, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; I want to see what indexes it has (and other stuff).

Comment: You have 4 things in the `WHERE` clause; are any of them very 'selective'?

Comment: Hello Rick, sorry for the late response but i hadent seen that someone responded, the length is needed to filter some unwanted extensions, pls can you explain ho can i do the sql_count_rows_found outside of ui thanks, and yes i will use r and c , i will post later as I am not at work the explain select

Comment: [Screenshot of Explain Function ](http://prntscr.com/agy7go)

@RickJames This is the Explain of the query , i dont know how to apply your SQL COUNT ROWS FOUND to this

Comment: What UI are you using?  (And there are 3 other questions still unanswered.)

Comment: :) sorry @RickJames , and thankfs for the help, updated the example with R and C , 
1) LENGTH(a.extension) = 6 => I use this to check if it is an External or Internal number, internal numbers are with 5 digits and external with 9 the 6 is a middle number if found 
2) Don't let your UI add SQL_COUNT_ROWS_FOUND => this is the part i dont know how to do 
3) The WHERE part is to filter not needed results, so the results obtained are very fiew in number
4) I am using DataTables and just started to experiment with AngularJS Tables 
.. continued..

Comment: .. I am starting to understand by now that mos part of my problem is the Transfer from Database Server to WebServer and than to Client Browser did some php.ini tuning i found around but dosent seem to help that much

Comment: Which part of the `WHERE` does the best job of filtering?  You could do some `SELECT COUNT(*)` with one piece at a time -- to get some idea of the answer.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.